# Simple Linear Regression - Prediction Interval and Non-constant variance

Tags: regression, prediction, heteroscedasticity

I have two questions about a simple linear regression model. I want to use test1 scores to predict test2 scores. I am using R software.

x=test1, y=test2, Let's say that both tests are scored from 1 to 50

I would use this code to fit the model:

```
fit=lm(y~x)
```

Then I plot the residuals vs. the fitted values and get a cone shape indicating non-constant variance. My questions are:

1. What is the best method to account for this non-constant variance? I know that I can use weighted least squares by adding weights to the lm function, but how do I know what weights to use? Also, how will this affect my prediction interval and what function or formula can I use to get a correct prediction interval? A link or reference would be greatly appreciated if you don't want to explain.
2. My test scores only go from 1 to 50. However, my prediction intervals will include values outside this range when predicting for values near the ends of the scale. For example, a prediction interval for x=50 may be (45,55). What do I do about this and what is this problem called? Again, a link or reference would be greatly appreciated if you don't want to explain.

My plot looks like the increasing plot shown here.

[image: I dont have the exact plot right now but it looks basically like the increasing plot here]

Comment: Can you show the plot with the cone-shape?

Comment: Thanks... but I meant "of your actual data". I understand what a cone shape looks like in a general sense, but the kind of advice I would give can depend on particular aspects of the situation that I can't judge from your description nor from a plot that isn't your data. A fan shape might be consistent with sd proportional to $x$ for example (in which case I have several possible options), but if the point of the fan would be clearly positive or negative, most of those options won't work.